# How do I make a powerset without using map or lambda in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, powerset

I'm trying to make a powerset in Haskell (I'm very new to it), and I can't figure out exactly what I need to do in order to make one without map. WITH map and lambda, I found this solution:

```
powerset :: Set a -> Set (Set a)
powerset [] = [[]]
powerset (head:tail) = powerset tail >>= \set ->[set, head:set]
powerset (x:xs) = map (x:) (powerset xs) ++ powerset xs
```

This is NOT what I want. I looked all over on other questions and couldn't find the answer I'm looking for. Help would be greatly appreciated!!

Edit: This is what I've come up with so far.. It obviously doesn't work but I'm trying!!

```
powerset :: Set a -> Set (Set a)
powerset [] = [[]]
powerset (x:xs) = [x + (powerset xs)] + powerset xs
```

Comment: What other ways are you interested in? List comprehensions? Also I think you forgot to say that you have defined `type Set a = [a]`, and you are not using the one from [`containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Set.html)

Comment: the errors you are not telling us is partly due to `(+)` only working on numeric types and not lists - you should rather use  `(++)` instead.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Yes, I'd like to use list comprehensions! Also yes, I did this before creating my function: type Set a = [a]
Also I will change to ++ :)

Comment: The lambda can be easily be replaced by a named function, either at the top level or in a where or let clause.

Comment: So, I changed it with ++, but I'm getting this error:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `[a]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for powerset :: Set a -> Set (Set a)
          at assignment2.hs:71:1
    In the first argument of `(++)', namely `x'
    In the expression: x ++ (powerset xs)
    In the first argument of `(++)', namely `[x ++ (powerset xs)]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there - if you want to use list comprehensions, which are equivalent to `map` in this case you only need a small step:

```
powerset (x:xs) = [x:ps | ps <- powerset xs] ++ powerset xs
```

<sub>What I am curious - why do you want to avoid `map`, it is one of the most important functional programming patterns you will find! But I guess that is not part of my answer - just a side note.</sub>

Comment: OMG thank you SO much! You just made everything make way more sense to me. I have seen list comprehensions before, but I didn't really understand them. This was super helpful :) Also, my instructor was wanting us to use list comprehensions so that we understood exactly what was happening. It's a coding languages class at TAMU! I completely agree that map is important.

Answer (score 1):

From comments:

> a' with [a]' a' is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for powerset :: Set a -> Set (Set a) at assignment2.hs:71:1 In the first argument of (++)', namely x' In the expression: x ++ (powerset xs) In the first argument of (++)', namely `[x ++ (powerset xs)]'

This is because `powerset` returns a `Set (Set a)` where `Set` is just an alias for lists. Note that `(++)` concatenates two lists of the same type. Since `x` is a `Set a`, it cannot be concatenated with a `Set (Set a)`. Instead, you should use the cons operator `(:)` which appends an element to the beginning of the list.

```
x : powerset xs
```

Comment: I also figured out that switching [[]] and [] on the second line fixed everything! It works now, with @epsilonhalbe 's solution! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @LauraAdams `switching [[]] and [] on the second line fixed everything` This might fix the compiler error, but now you have a logic error because you will just get one big long list, not a list of lists as you need.